# Disabled "Memory Usage" option in VS 2013 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 4. I create a project, compile it and start "Performance and Diagnostics" tool. When it starts the "Memory Usage" option is disabled. How can I enable it? Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to provide more info.  What kind of project is this?  Is the option categorized in the "Not Applicable Tools" section?

Comment: It is a WPF Project and the "Memory Usage" option is categorized in the "Not ApplicableTools". Same project, on a colleague's machine, has the option enabled.

Comment: No good explanation for that, particularly the "Not applicable" category.  Must be a configuration issue, you'd have to spin the repair/re-install wheel of fortune.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, "Memory Usage" option is available only on Windows 8.1 systems. In my case, VS2013 runs on Windows 7.